# Adding cordova-plugin-file error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to add "file" plugin to my Phonegap project, but it's returns errors:

```
d:\Android\projects\myProject>phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file
Error: Failed to fetch plugin git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm WARN cordova-plugin-camera@2.1.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@>=2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.2.0 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

What is the right way of adding "file" plugin to Phonegap/Cordova project?

p.s: I'm on Windows cmd.

**Update:**

Trying to add plugin with `--save` option enabled:

```
d:\Android\projects\myProject>phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save -d
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".

No version specified for cordova-plugin-file, retrieving version from package.json

Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0"

saving

Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\xampp\nodejs\npm.cmd install cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0 --save""

Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "D:\xampp\nodejs\npm.cmd install cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0 --save"

Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm WARN cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.2.0 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: try adding this in your config.xml - '<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file />'

Comment: `Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0 via registry.`

Comment: How did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its an error with the cordova version. Which version do you use it ?. Try with another version, for example 6.5.0

`npm i cordova@6.5.0`

Try again to install a plugin

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: didn't help. 
version of phonegapis 7.0.1